# How to make a range between dates and only some specific lines appear

Tags: r

The code below works fine. Notice that I have a function called `f3` and then I do `Output` to generate all the data obtained from `f3`. Everything is OK! But now my idea is to make a range between dates and only some specific lines of `Output` appear.

**Example:**

I want to see the `Time` value obtained in the range from `"2022-04-24"` to `"2022-04-25"`, that is, `Sunday` and `Monday`, so only the first and second line will appear. If I want to see between `"2022-04-24"` and `"2022-04-26"`, which includes `Sunday`, `Monday` and `Tuesday`, the 3 output lines will appear. If I want to see only one day, that is, the range `"2022-04-24"` to `"2022-04-24"`, only the second line will appear.

Is there any way to do this? I thought something like this:

```
  Output %>%
  arrange(match(Week, weekdays(seq(as.Date("2022-04-24"),as.Date("2022-04-25"), by = "day"))))
```

However, it didn't!

**Code executable:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)

df1<- structure(
list(
Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
date1 = c("2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06","2022-01-06"),
date2 = c("2022-01-02","2022-01-03","2022-01-04","2022-01-09"),
Week = c("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Sunday"),
DT=c(1,1,1,1),
Category = c("EFG", "ABC","EFG","EFG"),
Time = c(1,2,2,1)),row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")

      Id      date1      date2    Week DT Category Time
1  1 2022-01-06 2022-01-02  Sunday  1      EFG    1
2  1 2022-01-06 2022-01-03  Monday  1      ABC    2
3  1 2022-01-06 2022-01-03 Tuesday  1      EFG    2
4  1 2022-01-06 2022-01-09  Sunday  1      EFG    1


f3 <- function(df1) {
  
  nms <- c('Time|time')
  
  mtime <- df1 %>% 
    group_by(Id,Week = tools::toTitleCase(Week), Category,DT) %>% 
    summarise(across(matches(nms), mean, .names = 'Time',na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    mutate(Time = format(round(Time, digits = 2), nsmall = 2))
  
  return(mtime)
  
}
```

---

Generate for all datas

```
Output <- df1%>%f3()

    > Output
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     Id Week    Category    DT Time 
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
1     1 Monday  ABC          1 2.00 
2     1 Sunday  EFG          1 1.00 
3     1 Tuesday EFG          1 2.00
```

---

Generate for a specific data

```
Output %>% 
  filter(Id=="1",Week == "Monday", Category == "ABC",DT=="1")

     Id Week   Category    DT Time 
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
1     1 Monday ABC          1 2.00
```

---

Generate for a data range (**ERROR**)

```
Output %>%
  arrange(match(Week, weekdays(seq(as.Date("2022-04-24"),as.Date("2022-04-25"), by = "day"))))

     Id Week    Category    DT Time 
  <dbl> <chr>   <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
1     1 Monday  ABC          1 2.00 
2     1 Sunday  EFG          1 1.00 
3     1 Tuesday EFG          1 2.00
```

For this example above, only **Sunday** and **Monday** would have to appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% of your goals, as you might be making it a little more complicated than it needs to be. However, for your error, I don't think you need `arrange(match...`. You can instead use `filter` to keep only rows that have `Monday` or `Sunday`.

```
library(tidyverse)

Output %>%
  filter(Week %in% weekdays(seq(as.Date("2022-04-24"),as.Date("2022-04-25"), by = "day")))
```

**Output**

```
     Id Week   Category    DT Time 
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
1     1 Monday ABC          1 2.00 
2     1 Sunday EFG          1 1.00
```

In general, if you wanted to sort by the days of the week, then you could convert `Week` into a factor, then when you arrange by the column it will put them in order according to how you defined the level, rather than alphabetically.

```
Output %>%
  filter(Week %in% weekdays(seq(as.Date("2022-04-24"),as.Date("2022-04-25"), by = "day"))) %>%
  mutate(Week = factor(Week,
                levels = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"))) %>% 
  arrange(Week)

#     Id Week   Category    DT Time 
#  <dbl> <fct>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>
#1     1 Sunday EFG          1 1.00 
#2     1 Monday ABC          1 2.00
```

Comment: It worked, thanks so much @AndrewGB! Just one question: When I have data for every day of the week, it was out order in `Week`, for example, `Sunday` before `Monday`, do you know how to solve it?

Comment: @Antonio You can still use `arrange` for that, but I would make a new line for that in the pipe instead of trying to wrap it around another function. I added another option for arranging as well.